# How to push only to a branch of my fork of a Github repo, after a pull request has already been made

Tags: git, github, version-control

Say I cloned a public Github repo, called `REPO`.  I then made a branch, did some work, and submitted a work-in-progress pull request to `REPO`.  Whenever I push a new commit, it goes to both my clone, and `REPO`.  This kicks off time consuming CI tests on `REPO`.

I switch between working on two computers, and it would be nice to commit to my clone of the repo, without adding it to the current PR on `REPO`.  Then I could push, switch computers, and pull from the branch on my fork.  When I'm ready, I can push a batch of commits to the pull request on `REPO`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new branch (say, `feature`) from the branch you created pull request (say, `pr-branch`).

```
$ git checkout pr-branch       # checkout to 'pr-branch'
$ git checkout -b feature      # create and checkout to 'feature' branch
```

Then, when you are done with `feature` branch, merge the `feature` branch with the `pr-branch`.

```
$ git push origin feature      # push 'feature' branch changes to remote
$ git checkout pr-branch       # checkout to 'pr-branch'  
$ git pull origin feature      # pull 'feature' branch changes into local 'pr-branch'

$ git push origin pr-branch    # update remote 'pr-branch'
```

Now, your PR on `REPO` should be updated automatically since `pr-branch` is updated with `feature` branch commits/changes.

---

If you have to switch between two computers and work on `feature` branch then, just *push* your latest `feature` branch changes to remote and *pull* from another computer to start working from latest codes.

```
# computer-1
$ git pull origin feature
# do some commits here...
$ git push origin feature

# computer-2
$ git pull origin feature
# start working from latest codes and do commit...
$ git push origin feature
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `push` back to `origin`'s `pr-branch` at the end of the portion where you move your code from `feature` to `pr-branch`?